# Add, delete record by jquery

Tags: jquery

i want delete item when it was added, but when i click tag span, it not working.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img#add_file').click(function () {
        $('#file_tools').before('<div class="file_upload" id="f"><input name="file[]" type="file"> <span>del</span></div>');                                             
    });
    $('span').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: use `.on()` to bind events.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on("click", "span", function(){
        $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

**TIP:** `.on()` method helps you to bind events on future elements which has been created on the fly via javascript or ajax.

*Instead of `$(document)`, better to use `$("#file_tools").parent()` or if you know this parent element id or class.*

Comment: Should really be `.file_upload span` for the selector, since they don't want to incorrectly match other spans on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Add jquery functions like on(), bind() to click event like this :-

```
$("span").on("click", function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();
});


$("span").bind("click", function(){
        $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

Note :- Events like on(), bind() have the capability to bind events to dynamically created DOM elements.

Comment: are you sure `bind()` can do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a scope issue in your code. A solution is to write like this :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img#add_file').click(function () {
        $('#file_tools').before('<div class="file_upload" id="f"><input name="file[]" type="file"> <span>del</span></div>');    

        // Place those instructions here!
        $('span').click(function () {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Bye